# Regex to convert property

Tags: regex, notepad++

I own a huge file of properties that must be entered into a database. All properties have the key and value pattern, like this: key = value.
So I have a pattern of separating the data by the = sign.

How to turn this

```
management.security.enabled=false
```

in that

```
('management.security.enabled','false')
```

in Notepad++ ?

Comment: Is there a reason why find/replace all isn't sufficient for this?

Comment: Why does this require regex?

Comment: @Mako212 
this is part of a huge property file, so the regex to make work easier

Comment: @Aran-Fey 
I explained above

Comment: You can match the string with `management\.security\.enabled=false`, but I still don't see how that helps.

Comment: Nope, you didn't explain anything. It's completely unclear why you can't use a simple string search/replace operation. Regex is about pattern matching, and you haven't explained what kind of pattern you want to match. You've given us a single piece of text, no pattern. As it is at the moment, the regex `management\.security\.enabled=false` answers your question.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I explained my problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace every property with your bracket notation search for

```
(\S+)=(\S+)
```

and replace it with

```
\('$1','$2'\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find what : `^([^=]+)=(.*)$`

Replace with : `\('$1', '$2'\)`

---

Reference: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions